# Disable copying of file

Tags: filesystem, copy-paste

I want to provide a mac to a remote worker with my project folder. Its ok if they try to take pics of the code but i dont want them to copy the whole folder. Is it possible? how?

UPDATE:

Can I just create new user account(non-admin) and disable file copying somehow?

Comment: Why pictures? If they're able to read the code, couldn't they just copy-paste it into a document on their computer? There's no reasonable way to prevent that.

Comment: I just want to disable direct copying. I really cant do anything if they see the code and copy it manually.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to disable copying that way. If someone can read a file, they should be able to copy it. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is to simply add the code to a source control and grant the user view access only.

Its not exactly what you asked for but it might help.

In addition you can print the files as PDF, that way it will be like a picture where there is no copy-paste but there are so many easy ways to OCR images.